# How should I test my new mode?

Tags: major-mode

I am trying to create a new mode for Emacs lisp, let's call it `xyz-mode.el`.

In testing the mode, I want to re-run `xyz-mode.el` on a potential target file, let's say `abc.xyz`. In other words, as I edit `xyz-mode.el`, I want to reload the mode into Emacs so that `abc.xyz` is viewable under the modified configuration. To be absolutely clear, what I want to do is as follows:

1. I edit `xyz-mode.el` to change, say, the syntax for comments;
2. I re-load `xyz-mode.el`
3. I re-view abc.xyz to see whether my changes to `xyz-mode.el` have had the intended consequences.

I'm not talking about editing `abc.xyz`, but about editing `xyz-mode.el` then reloading.

What is the best way to re-run `xyz-mode.el` and try to re-view the subject file `abc.xyz`? I have tried using `eval-buffer` but this does not work correctly. I am currently killing Emacs itself and restarting, which is time-consuming.

Comment: To the extent that you can provide a minimal working example of your mode, the forum readers may be able to give you some ideas regarding how to test it.  As it stands now, without a crystal ball, I don't see how anyone can help you.  You may also wish to consider reddit with the Emacs tab -- all the time I see people posing their creations with questions like:  What do you think?  How can I improve upon what I have written?  Etc.  emacs.stackexchange.com is more geared towards what everyone would agree upon as being a distinct question with only a few or just one correct answer.

Comment: You can do essentially the same thing you're with `find-alternate-file`, which should shorten re-opening a file to simply `C-x C-v RET`, provided your mode is already associated with file extension and you're using a file for your tests.

Comment: @lawlist - I would be delighted to show you the content of the file, but I'm asking about reloading the mode file without killing the buffer or stopping the editor, so the content of the mode itself is not even slightly relevant to any potential answer.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 - thanks for your input. I am using "Local variables:" to specify the file type, which works correctly. I want to re-read the xyz-mode.el file, not the file being input. It seems this question was not clear enough, so I'll edit it to clarify.

Comment: There's `load-file` and `eval-buffer` which can be called with `M-x`, but these won't work for things like declarations with `defvar` and `defconst`, which you can (re)evaluate with `C-x C-e` after the sexp or `C-M-x`.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 - Thanks for your input. I was able to get to some sort of hazy understanding with your answer plus the information at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html. It seems I still have to kill the abc.xyz file and re-open it even using eval-defun (C-M-x).

Comment: OK, C-M-x followed by "find-alternate-file" actually does work. Thanks.

Comment: This is just my experience, yours may be very different: don't go for reloading your code in the Emacs you use to program.  Spawn a separate Emacs for testing and then after you done testing kill it.  Create a special minimal init file for this purpose, and don't connect to `emacsclient` from the testing copy that you have.  Yes, it will be slower, but much more surely you will not be affected by accidental stuff you introduced, and, even more importantly, infinite loops will not stall your working editor.

Comment: @wvxvw It's also possible to just use emacsen with no init files to test once in a while to check whether nothing depends on your personal configuration. Incremental development is the biggest thing that defines lisps in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: `M-x eval-buffer` in the Lisp buffer then `M-x normal-mode` in the XYZ mode buffer.

---

To test the changes in your mode, you need to do two things: load the modified Lisp code, and apply the modifications to the buffer.

To load the modified Lisp code, `M-x eval-buffer` in `xyz-mode.el` mostly works, but there are a few limitations. This runs all the code in the buffer, and in particular it updates all the function definitions. However the values of variables set by `defvar` and the like (`defconst`, `defcustom`, `defface`) are not updated: `defvar` does not change the value of a variable that already has one. Updating the value of an existing variable when evaluating a `defvar` form is a special feature of `eval-defun` (`C-M-x`). Keeping the value of an existing variable is the right thing when it has been set by the user, but when it was set by a previous version of the code, you aren't testing the new code.

If the `xyz-mode` code was originally loaded by `load`, `require` or the like, you can run `M-x unload-feature xyz-mode RET` to unload all the definitions provided by the loaded module, then re-run the code that would load or autoload the module (e.g. re-evaluate `(autoload 'xyz-mode "xyz-mode")`). This way you'll get the new value for all variables, as long as those variables were loaded as part of the module. Also, if you removed some definition as part of your changes, it won't exist anymore, so you don't risk validating code that's actually using a definition that no longer exists. But note that variables and functions that were created with `C-M-x` during development won't have been unloaded since they weren't recorded as being part of the module.

Whatever method you use to load the changed implementation of the major mode, you also need to apply the changes to the existing buffer. Reloading the Lisp code applies some changes automatically, but some things require initialization in each buffer (e.g. syntax table, keymap, sometimes font lock settings). Re-run the major mode function in the `abc.xyz` buffer: `M-x xyz-mode RET` or (assuming the mode is the default for a file by that name) `M-x normal-mode RET` or `M-x revert-buffer RET`.

If this was a minor mode, turn it off and back on.

There is still a risk that the new code accidentally depends on some old feature that still exists in your session. Therefore, I recommend that from time to time, you run a new Emacs session to test the file. Keep your existing Emacs session open and run a new one just with the `abc.xyz` file to see that all is well. Do keep your existing Emacs session, so that for instance if you wrote a new function and then accidentally deleted it, you can recover it through undo or through the kill ring.